# Plotting a SEM Actor-Partner Interdependence Model after runMI()

Tags: r, plot, r-mice, r-lavaan, semplot

I am using multiply-imputed data to run an Actor-Partner Interdependence Model (APIM; [Cook & Kenny, 2005](https://psycnet.apa.org/record/2005-01893-002)). I am using `mice` to impute my data and for reference, I am using [this resource guide](https://randilgarcia.github.io/week-dyad-workshop/APIM_SEM.html) for constructing my APIM with `lavaan`.

As far as I can tell, there is only [one other StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59304910/supply-lavaan-mi-object-runmi-semtools-to-sempaths-semplot-in-r) that is related my issue. However, I was unable to directly apply that answer to my APIM. There is also a [three-year-old Github issue with `semPaths`](https://github.com/SachaEpskamp/semPlot/issues/23) that doesn't seem to have made any progress since the other StackOverflow user posted about it.

I tried adjusting the other StackOverflow answer for my APIM by filtering out everything except the two actor effects and two partner effects. I think I'm almost there; if you compare the summary output with my third attempt at plotting, the summary estimates are similar to what's plotted by `semPaths()` but not exact.

What's causing the plotted estimates to be off? Is there a better way of plotting `lavaan.mi` objects that feels less hacky?

```
library(mice)
library(lavaan)
library(tidyverse)
library(faux)
library(missMethods)
library(semTools)
library(semPlot)
set.seed(1234)

## prepwork
# generate data
df <- faux::rnorm_multi(n = 100, vars = 4, mu = 3, sd = 1, varnames = c("x1", "x2", "y1", "y2")) %>%
  mutate(id = rep(1:100)) %>% select(id, everything()) %>%
  missMethods::delete_MCAR(cols = c("x1", "x2", "y1", "y2"), p = .15)
  
# make lavaan object
myapim <- "x1  ~ a1*y1; x2  ~ a2*y2; x1  ~ p12*y2; x2  ~ p21*y1; y1 ~ mx1*1; y2 ~ mx2*1; x1 ~ my1*1; x2 ~ my2*1
           y1 ~~ vx1*y1; y2 ~~ vx2*y2; x1 ~~ vy1*x1; x2 ~~ vy2*x2; y2 ~~ cx*y1; x2 ~~ cy*x1 
           a_diff := a1 - a2; p_diff := p12 - p21; k1 := p12/a1; k2 := p21/a2
           k_diff := k1 - k2; i_diff := my1 - my2; a_ave := (a1 + a2)/2; p_ave := (p12 + p21)/2
           i_ave := (my1 +my2)/2; sum1 := (p12 + a1)/2; sum2 := (p21 + a2)/2; cont1 := a1 - p12; cont2 := a2 - p21
"
apimd <- lavaan::sem(myapim, data = df, fixed.x = FALSE, missing = "default")

# impute data
imp <- mice::mice(df, m = 5, maxit = 10, seed = 1234, printFlag = FALSE)

# conduct SEM
sem_model <- runMI(model = myapim, data = imp, fun = "sem", miPackage = "mice", seed = 1234)

## plot
# try to plot lavaan.mi
semPaths(sem_model, what = "est", sizeMan = 25, sizeMan2 = 10, 
         label.cex = 1.2, edge.label.position = 0.45, edge.label.cex = 1.5) #  error
#> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable) : unable to find an inherited method for function 'semPlotModel_S4' for signature '"lavaan.mi"'

# try to use other StackOverflow answer directly
other_model <- sem(myapim,  data = df)
SEMPLOT <- semPlot::semPlotModel(other_model)
desired_output <- data.frame(standardizedsolution(sem_model))
SEMPLOT@Pars$std <- desired_output$est.std # error
#> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, std, value = structure(c(0.164373878998654, : replacement has 27 rows, data has 14

# try to adjust the other StackOverflow answer for my APIM
baseplot <- semPlot::semPlotModel(other_model)
desired_output <- data.frame(standardizedsolution(sem_model))
desired_output <- desired_output %>% filter(op != ":=")
baseplot@Pars$est <- desired_output$est.std
semPaths(baseplot, 
         nCharNodes = 0, what = "est",
         fade = FALSE, layout = "tree2", 
         rotation = 2, style = "ram",
         intercepts = FALSE, residuals = FALSE, 
         optimizeLatRes = TRUE, curve = 3.1, nDigits = 3,
         sizeMan = 12, sizeMan2 = 10, 
         label.cex = 1.2, edge.label.position = 0.45, edge.label.cex = 1.5)
```

[image]

```
# I only pasted part of summary() to keep it short
> summary(sem_model)
lavaan.mi object based on 5 imputed data sets. 
See class?lavaan.mi help page for available methods. 

Convergence information:
The model converged on 5 imputed data sets 

Rubin's (1987) rules were used to pool point and SE estimates across 5 imputed data sets, and to calculate degrees of freedom for each parameter's t test and CI.

Parameter Estimates:

  Standard errors                             Standard
  Information                                 Expected
  Information saturated (h1) model          Structured

Regressions:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  t-value       df  P(>|t|)
  x1 ~                                                         
    y1        (a1)    0.162    0.111    1.456   12.345    0.170
  x2 ~                                                         
    y2        (a2)   -0.005    0.112   -0.046   75.147    0.963
  x1 ~                                                         
    y2       (p12)    0.209    0.122    1.714   37.386    0.095
  x2 ~                                                         
    y1       (p21)    0.049    0.103    0.478   47.391    0.635
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's causing the plotted estimates to be off?

I just left a comment on the earlier post you linked to, informing them that `standardizedSolution()` is not for `lavaan.mi` objects.  You should use an actual `class?lavaan.mi` method, something like:

```
desired_output <- summary(sem_model, standardized = "std.all",
                          ## so you can check it more easily:
                          output = "data.frame")
```

And carefully compare the rows and columns of `desired_output` to those of `baseplot@Pars` to make sure your replacement makes sense.

Also, you only need to set the `miPackage=` when you want to impute within the `runMI()` call, which is not recommended.  You did the right thing by imputing first, but that is when setting your seed counts.

```
# impute data
imp <- mice::mice(df, m = 5, maxit = 10,
                  seed = 1234, printFlag = FALSE)

# conduct SEM
sem_model <- sem.mi(model = myapim, data = imp)
```

> Is there a better way of plotting lavaan.mi objects that feels less hacky?

Not yet.  Of course, the easiest and safest way to make this work would be if `semPaths()` checked for the `lavaan.mi` class and correctly extracted the necessary information itself.  I'll make a note to send Sacha a pull request for `semPlot` when I have time to work on `semTools` again.